# create vertical brackets that span over several rows

Tags: algorithms

I just came across a snipet of codes where a long vertical bracket is used to mark a loop.  I really like that.  I wonder what is the best way to implement this in latex?  Thanks[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like it was made with [`algorithm2e`](https://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[vlined]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\DontPrintSemicolon
\For{\(i = 0\) \KwTo \(k-1\)}{
    Pick \(a \in [2, \hdots, n-1]\).\;
    \(b \leftarrow a^{n-1} \mod n\).\;
    \lIf{\(b \neq 1\)}{\KwRet}
}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I did not know that such packages exist -- thanks!